# How do I get LibreOffice 4.0 running on an iBook G4?

Tags: macos, ibook

My brother just got an iBook G4 running 10.4.2 (Tiger), and we were trying to get LibreOffice 4.0 (the latest version) installed. The machine insists that the LibreOffice package is damaged or incomplete. However, my MacBook Pro, which runs 10.7.5 (Lion) runs the same package just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry folks, the problem turns out that I wasn't using the PowerPC package - I was using the Intel package.